# Recursive calls leading to a stack overflow exception

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
public class TestClass {

    TestClass classIn = new TestClass(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass classIn = new TestClass(); 
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is leading to a stack overflow?

Comment: Just why would it *not* lead to a SO? That recursion never ends, and each call takes some stack space.

Comment: Use a line by line debugger. You'll see the effect very quickly.

Comment: I think this question is caused by a complete lack of understanding as to what a stack overflow actually is.

Comment: I thought it was a website for programming questions.

Comment: @P45Imminent That's StackOverflow, not a stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 2):

The error would be because whenever you are trying to create an instance of `TestClass` , it again tries to create instance of itself in the line -

```
TestClass classIn = new TestClass();
```

And this continues on recursively, till the stack overflows. Remove this line and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `classIn` instance variable is initialized each time you create an instance of `TestClass`. Therefore, each time you create an instance of `TestClass`, you immediately create another instance, which leads to an infinite recursion.

The first instance is created in your main method :

```
TestClass classIn = new TestClass();
```

Before the constructor of `TestClass` is executed, the instance variables (`classIn` in your case) are initialized, so another instance is created, which triggers the creation of another instance, and so on... (until the stack overflows).

Answer (score 1):

As people mentioned, you are in an infinite recursion and the computer has only so much it can do before the stack overflows. A very important rule when dealing with recursion is: **ALWAYS, ALWAYS, HAVE A BASE CLASS!**

Think of the factorial recursion example:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
if(n = 0)
  return 1;
else
  return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Note the base case where you, the human, can manually calculate it. This case is the one that prevents an overflow as without your code will just keep looping itself. Assume I have 3 without that  base case. So you will get 3 * 2 * 1 * 0 * -1 * -2 ....